# MPI_Allreduce not synchronizing properly

Tags: parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi, distributed-computing, reduce

A bit new to MPI, but I am looking at a code and it does not appear they are properly using `MPI_Allreduce()`.

Here is the code snippet (in Fortran, but it should be readable to others).

```
      do n = 1, ntts_total    !ntts_total is some large number
         send_buffer(1) = some_array(n)        !send_buffer is a size 2 array of doubles
         send_buffer(2) = proc_id

         !recv_buffer is a size 2 array of doubles
         call MPI_Allreduce(send_buffer, recv_buffer, nprocs, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 

         if (proc_id == INT(recv_buffer(2))) then
            this%n_tots = this%n_tots + 1
            my_id(this%n_tots) = n
         end if
      end do
```

What they're trying to do is for each pass through the loop, each process stores some value in some_array and the processor id as the first and second elements in `send_buffer`, respectively. Then they use `MPI_Allreduce` to find the minimum element as well as the processor rank the min element is located, and then distribute the result to all processors.

Then they do an if check afterwards.

But I think in the current state, the synchronizing is off. I think `MPI_barrier()` should be called right before and after the `MPI_Allreduce()`, something like this:

```
         call MPI_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
         !recv_buffer is a size 2 array of doubles
         call MPI_Allreduce(send_buffer, recv_buffer, nprocs, MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
         call MPI_barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

If there's no barriers before and after then each processor would not be synching and it could lead to something like processor 1 sending data from n = 1 and processor 2 sending data from n = 2, and the reduction would be performed on different iterations.

Is what I am thinking correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the third parameter be `1` instead of `nprocs`, since it is the number of `MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION` elements in the send buffer?

Comment: @rtoijala You're right! Thanks for catching that. Is `MPI_barrier` still needed?

Comment: I do not believe so, but I cannot right now find where it would be said in the MPI standard.

Comment: @rtoijala Hmm I see. Something is off with the code that appears to be related to synchronization. I am printing the global buffer at each iteration, and the receive buffers are not outputting the same value for all processors.

Comment: @rtoijala https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1.3/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html Here it says the function is thread-safe.

Comment: @rtoijala Also, in your first comment, you meant the third parameter should be 2 and not 1 right? Since the number of elements in the send buffer is 2?

Comment: Your datatype is `MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION`, and you have two double precision numbers, so from MPI's point of view, you have one element.

Comment: The standard does not require you to insert `MPI_Barrier()`. Also note there is an implicit barrier in `MPI_Allreduce()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ah I see. It appears that at least one of my processors hangs inside the `MPI_Allreduce()` sometimes (not all the time). Any clue what could be causing this?

Comment: Either a bug in MPI or your app. Try inserting a barrier before allreduce and see if some tasks are now stuck in the barrier.